# Why does the presence of SBT_OPTS cause SBT to relocate -D parameters?

Tags: sbt

## Version

I'm using SBT 0.13.16 on Ubuntu 16.04, installed via the standard Ubuntu package.

## Problem

SBT seems to transpose the position of `-D` parameters provided on the command line, based on whether or not `SBT_OPTS` has been set.

## Example

Given the following command:

```
sbt clean -Denvironment=qa 'test-only MyTestClass'
```

Without an `SBT_OPTS` environment variable defined, `-D` properties set on the command line get passed to the java command. This is demonstrated below showing both the initial sbt process (11999) and the spawned child process (12053) e.g.

```
myuser  11999 11998  0 11:46 ?        00:00:00 bash /opt/sbt/bin/sbt clean -Denvironment=qa -Dservice=brm test-only MyTestClass
myuser  12053 11999 99 11:46 ?        00:01:10 java -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Denvironment=qa -jar /opt/sbt/bin/sbt-launch.jar clean test-only MyTestClass
```

However when an `SBT_OPTS` environment variable is set, for example as follows:

```
SBT_OPTS=-Dsbt.boot.properties=/home/myuser/.sbt/sbt.boot.properties -Dsbt.override.build.repos=true -Dmy.repository.host=https://nexus.mydomain.com/
```

...the `-D` properties provided om the command line get moved to the right and are instead passed to the `sbt-launch.jar` e.g.

```
myuser   9123  9122  0 11:45 ?        00:00:00 bash /usr/bin/sbt clean -Denvironment=qa test-only MyTestClass
myuser   9186  9123 99 11:45 ?        00:00:57 java -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Dsbt.boot.properties=/home/myuser/.sbt/sbt.boot.properties -Dsbt.override.build.repos=true -Dmy.repository.host=https://nexus.mydomain.com/ -jar /usr/share/sbt/bin/sbt-launch.jar clean -Denvironment=qa test-only MyTestClass
```

The consequence of this is that the `environment` system property becomes inaccessible within the SBT build.

I've read a fair bit of the SBT documentation but am yet to find anything that describes this behaviour. Is this desired/ expected behaviour?

Many thanks!

Edd